# Lambda functions with template parameters, not in function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

Why does the first call not compile?

```
auto get1 = []<int B>() { return B; };
auto get2 = []<typename B>(B b) { return b; };

int main()
{
    get1<5>(); // error: no match for operator<
    get2(5);   // ok
}
```

The reason I use this, is an expression repeated many times in code.

Of course I can use a real function template, but just I am curious WHY.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is easier to understand if you consider what the equivalent class type looks like to your `get1`:

```
struct get1_t {
    template <int B> operator()() const { return B; }
};

get1_t get1;

get1<5>(); // error
```

You're trying to provide an explicit template parameter to the call operator, but syntactically you're doing what looks like providing template parameters for `get1` itself (i.e. as if `get1` were a variable template). In order to provide the template parameter for the call operator, you have to do that directly:

```
get1.operator()<5>(); // ok
```

Or restructure the call operator to take something deducible:

```
template <int B> struct constant { };
get1(constant<5>{});
```

---

Or restructure the whole thing to actually be the variable template that it looks like it is:

```
template <int B>
auto get1 = [] { return B; };
```

Now, `get1<5>` is itself a lambda, that you're invoking. That is, rather than a lambda with a call operator template we have a variable template lambda that is itself not a template.

Comment: @Bergi It's the same kind of thing as `get1<5>()`